# SharePoint is still using 14 hive after upgrade to 2013

Tags: upgrade

maybe it is a common problem.
After we upgraded site collection to 2013 it is still referring to 14 hive for features, layouts, controls etc., which causes the errors on the site. Is there any way to convince SharePoint to use 15 hive?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you referring to custom features/WSP or to standard artifacts?

Answer (score 2):

That, SharePoint 2013 has a SharePoint 2010 mode. meaning, there is a 14 hive that gets installed when the setup and configuration is complete. After installing SP2013 it will create both 14 & 15 hive folders (its normal).

In SharePoint 2013 it’s possible to install both SharePoint 2010 and 2013 solutions, which is supported by having two folders – one for the Sp2010 (“14″) hive files and one for the SP 2013 (“15″) hive files
- See more at: http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/11/why-14-hive-folder-still-exist-for.html#sthash.I4TnCbTy.
http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/11/why-14-hive-folder-still-exist-for.html